# c read from file and get string between two characters

Tags: c, file, substring

I have a text file chat.txt in this variation:

```
[23.05.2013 20:10:05] [imo.skype] NibbleByte: Hello

[23.05.2014 20:10:05] [imo65.skype] NibbleBdsfyte: Hesdf :)

[23.05.2015 20:10:05] [imo69.skypeeee] NibbledsfByte: How are you?
```

I try to read file and susbstring date, client(imo), protocol, username and message.

For example:

```
date: 23.05.2013 20:10:05

client: imo

protocol: skype

username: NibbleByte

message: Hello
```

After this i have to make it in linked list, but my problem is here how to read it. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Can you demonstrate anything you have tried?

Comment: I try something like this - http://goo.gl/RECj17 . to make a flags when on word is start and when it is over..but i'm not sure that i'm on right way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses scansets to parse the line.
The scanset `%29[^]]` scans up to 29 characters that are not `]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *pf = NULL;
    char line[500] = {0};
    char date[30] = {0};
    char client[30] = {0};
    char protocol[30] = {0};
    char username[30] = {0};
    char message[300] = {0};

    if ( ( pf = fopen ( "chat.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf ( " could not open file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    while ( fgets ( line, sizeof ( line), pf)) {
        if ( ( sscanf ( line," [%29[^]]] [%29[^.].%29[^]]] %29[^:]: %299[^\n]%*c"
        , date
        , client
        , protocol
        , username
        , message)) == 5) {
            printf ( "date : %s\n", date);
            printf ( "client : %s\n", client);
            printf ( "protocol : %s\n", protocol);
            printf ( "username : %s\n", username);
            printf ( "message : %s\n", message);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```